# RoR: fetch has_many association through another has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following official documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html at section 4.3.3.4

I have following models:

```
class Nomination < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :festival
  has_many :festival_histories, -> { includes :awards }
  attr_accessible :name
end

class FestivalHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :awards
  belongs_to :nomination
  belongs_to :festival
end

class Award < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :festival_history
  belongs_to :case, inverse_of: :awards
  has_attached_file :image
  attr_accessible :name, :festival_history_id, :image
end
```

Which looks very similar (for me) to example in documentation.

But when I do in console:

```
 n = Nomination.first
 n.festival_histories.awards
```

I get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `awards' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_FestivalHistory:0x000001019cd400>
```

I've reloaded console, so issue is not there for sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with documentation:)

As **JTG** said, you couldn't get awards on all festival_histories, only on specific history.

The difference is:

**With** `include` option:

```
n = Nomination.first
Nomination Load (0.4ms) SELECT "nominations".* FROM "nominations" ORDER BY "nominations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

n.festival_histories
FestivalHistory Load (25.5ms)  SELECT "festival_histories".* FROM "festival_histories" WHERE "festival_histories"."nomination_id" = ?  [["nomination_id", 1]]
Award Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "awards".* FROM "awards" WHERE "awards"."festival_history_id" IN (1)

n.festival_histories.first.awards
NO QUERY!
```

**Without** `include` option:

```
n = Nomination.first
Nomination Load (0.4ms) SELECT "nominations".* FROM "nominations" ORDER BY "nominations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

n.festival_histories
FestivalHistory Load (25.5ms)  SELECT "festival_histories".* FROM "festival_histories" WHERE "festival_histories"."nomination_id" = ?  [["nomination_id", 1]]

n.festival_histories.first.awards
Award Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "awards".* FROM "awards" WHERE "awards"."festival_history_id" = ?  [["festival_history_id", 1]]
```

I think difference is obvious now:)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Nomination < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :festival
  has_many :festival_histories, -> { includes :awards }
  has_many :awards, through: :festival_histories
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

Then you can call

```
Nomination.first.awards
```

Comment: yeap, I know that way around, but I'm trying to figure out - is it a mistake in documentation?

Comment: Possibly. I think it's probably an attempt to get across the idea without using too much code.

For example, they could have shown a code-block with a loop that goes through each of the customer's orders and displays it's line_items. Perhaps something like @customer -> orders -> line_items makes more sense?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's going wrong in you console, since festival_histories is an a collection of records, you cannot get the `awards` for a collection, only an individual record.  So instead of

```
n = Nomination.first
n.festival_histories.awards
```

You need

```
n = Nomination.first
n.festival_histories.each { |r| puts r.awards}
```

to see the awards for each `festival_history`.

(So yes, how you are `include:` the `:awards` for lazy loading is working, and it's not a mistake in the documentation ;))